# make words bold start with *

Tags: php, string

all the words in a string start with * should be bold.
This is what I have tried so far:

```
$string = "This is *a string to *check *bold";
echo preg_replace('/*(\w+)/', '<b>\1</b>', $string);
```

this is giving me error:

> This is *a string to *check *bold Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation
>   failed: nothing to repeat at offset 0 in...

Comment: Why not enable `error_reporting`? The `$var = print $expr;` will just assign a boolean btw.

Comment: Remove the print in the assignment and escape the `*` in the regex check

Comment: The mark down pseudo standard for wiki like text would have pairs of `*`: `*bold text*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong `preg_replace()` regex

`*` is special character in regex and should be escaped. I used `#` as delimiter for better visiblity.

Check code below:

```
$string = "This is *a string to *check *bold";
echo preg_replace('#\*(\w+)#', '<b>$1</b>', $string);
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working fine outside a loop, how can i make it to work in a loop, like while?

Comment: show me the loop then I can answer you. Probably it has something in common with newlines so add `s` modifer to regex `'#\*(\w+)#s'` but for now it's a guess

Comment: If this answer satisfy you then please accept so question can be closed. And you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "This is *a string to *check *bold";
echo preg_replace('/\*(\w+)/', '<b>\1</b>', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape "*"

so the regex will become

> *([\w]+)

```
  $string = "This is *a string to *check *bold";
  echo preg_replace('@\*([\w]+)@', '<b>$1</b>', $string);
```